# How to properly launch an OpenShift v3 app

Tags: docker, openshift-origin, kubernetes

As I am trying to launch a sample OpenShift v 3 (Docker/Kubernetes) app with this command:

```
_output/local/go/bin/osc create -f examples/hello-openshift/hello-pod.json
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Post https://localhost:8443/api/v1beta2/pods?namespace=default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

which is also confirmed by this message:

```
http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:58393: remote error: bad certificate
```

What adjustments do I need to make in order to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift (on startup) generates a root self-signed certificate and a set of client certificates.  The client is trying to talk to the server, but getting rejected because the client is loading certs from the root CA.

You can set the KUBECONFIG= environment variable and pass the path of the admin .kubeconfig file (by default, typically $(pwd)/openshift.local.certificates/admin/.kubeconfig.

You can also pass --insecure-skip-tls-verify when you invoke `osc`, but running with certificates will be more secure by default and once authorization is added, you'll be identified by the client cert that is bundled with that .kubeconfig.